# How to protect an interpreter's native call stack from garbage collection?

Tags: c, garbage-collection, stack, lisp, interpreter

I'm writing a Lisp interpreter in C. Each Lisp object is represented by a `struct LispObject *` with a `type` field to indicate whether it's an int, symbol, cons, etc. I've implemented a global environment as a hash table containing pairs of names and values.

`LispObject`s are always dynamically allocated with `malloc`. Whenever a new object is created, it's added to a list of weak references. When the garbage collector runs, it marks all objects reachable from the global environment and then sweeps the weak references and frees unmarked objects.

It's easy to protect the global environment from garbage collection. What I'm stuck on is how to protect local Lisp objects. To be clear, I have not yet implemented Lisp functions. What I'm asking is how to protect local C variables of type `LispObject *`. For example, `eval` is a C function that takes a `LispObject *` expression, applies the rules of evaluation, and returns a `LispObject *` value. I need to protect local `LispObject *` variables in `eval` (and other C functions that deal with Lisp objects) from garbage collection until the function returns.

What would be the cleanest way to do this? Is there some way to mark any `LispObject`s that are reachable from the C call stack?

I've considered implementing a separate stack used only for storing local Lisp objects that shouldn't be garbage collected, but that feels clunky because then local `LispObject *` variables are stored on the C call stack and on the garbage collection stack, and I have to manually push and pop objects in order to call C functions. Ideally, Lisp objects would automatically be protected while they exist in the local scope and then would automatically lose that protection upon going out of scope.

Full code: https://notabug.org/jtherrmann/lisp-in-c

Comment: You also have to protect object that outlives the C calls stack (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funarg_problem)

Answer (score 1):

I assume your GC is a precise GC. You need first to *define* when your GC is possibly called. A common scenario is to have each allocating routine possibly call the GC.

You need to write a routine which scans your call stack for local roots. So you need to have a machinery which register these local variables to your GC. In other words, you should **explicit your *interpreter*'s call stack** (or adopt some [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) approach).

A possibility might be to *explicit* your local frames as some `struct`. Look for example into what Ocaml runtime does (read its section [§20.5  Living in harmony with the garbage collector](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#sec441)) or into my old (unmaintained) [Qish](http://starynkevitch.net/basile/qishintro.html) GC. For example, you could adopt the convention that each local interpreter frame is in some `_` local variable (a `struct`) and use that. In my [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) project I would code something nearly equivalent (after preprocessor expansion) to this, for a C routine `crout` having a pointer argument `a` and two local pointers `b` and  `c`

```
 void crout(struct callingframe_st *cf, LispObject*a) {
   struct mycallframe_st {
      struct callingframe_st* from;
      int nbloc;
      LispObject* aa;
      LispObject* bb;
      LispObject* cc;
   } _;
   memset(&_, 0, sizeof(_));
   _.from = cf;
   _.nbloc = 3; // the current frame has 3 locals: aa, bb, cc
   _.aa = a;
   #define a _.aa
   #define b _.bb
   #define c _.cc
```

Then the body of `crout` follows. It would pass `(struct callingframe_st*)(&_)` to appropriate routines. At the end, be sure to  `#undef a` etc...
Your GC called from your allocation routines has to take `(struct callingframe_st *)(&_)` as argument (giving the current call frame).

So of course, your `b_cons`, assuming it can *indirectly* call your GC, should be declared as

```
LispObject* b_cons(struct callingframe_st*cf, 
                    LispObject * car, LispObject * cdr);
```

Otherwise, you need to define *when* your GC is called.

---

You need to understand how Garbage Collection works (and the difference between precise and conservative GC). I strongly recommend reading the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) or at least Paul Wilson's old *[Uniprocessor Garbage Collection Techniques](https://www3.nd.edu/~dthain/courses/cse40243/spring2006/gc-survey.pdf)* paper. You could adopt the convention that all your routines are following the [A-normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form) style (so you never code directly in C `f(g(x),h(x,y))` with all `f`, `g`, `h` perhaps doing object allocation).

You might also use some *existing* precise GC, such as [Ravenbrook MPS](https://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps).

Otherwise, use some *conservative* GC like [Boehm's GC](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/).

Look also into the source code of existing free software interpreters having some GC.

Read also Queinnec's [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) book

---

> I have to manually push and pop objects in order to call C functions.

That might be a good idea (but you then need to rewrite most of your code, and you may actually define your own [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) machinery). Look into what [Lua](https://www.lua.org/) or [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/) or [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) bytecode interpreter or [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) Elisp interpreter are doing.

---

For completion, you might consider (it is really hard, and I don't recommend going that route, since it would take many years of work) writing some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to generate and/or add ad-hoc call frame metadata and/or generate call frame related code to help your precise GC. This is really difficult. IIRC, [CLASP](https://github.com/clasp-developers) is doing something similar (above Clang, not GCC).

---

Don't forget that garbage collection is a *whole-program* thing.

Comment: I am not suggesting scanning *directly* the C call stack. I am suggesting *expliciting* each call frame of your interpreter.

Comment: Could you define "expliciting" a call frame?

Comment: Like my `struct mycallframe_st {` ... `} _;`

Comment: OK, thank you for the detailed reply. I'm new to C so I'm not able to immediately grasp these examples, but I will spend some time studying them.

I'm also new to GC, but I think I do understand mark-and-sweep fairly well. I'm just having difficulty understanding how to to include the C call stack in the root set, given that I didn't implement the call stack so I don't have direct access to it.

Comment: I gave several references that you should read. Be sure to understand that a GC is a *whole program* thing. Notice that I am not saying to scan the C call stack, but to scan your interpreter's call stack.

Comment: BTW, if you are newbie in C and newbie in GC techniques, your goal (writing a naive Lisp-like interpreter) might be overambitious. You need to learn a lot

Comment: You really should spend days in reading much more. GC is a whole program thing, so you'll end up rewriting most of your current C code

Comment: Don't let Basile stop you though as you learn a lot about a language by implementing a subset of it in itself and in not itself at least once. Though I have never bothered to even do GC in mine since it's always something you can fix later :-)